# Unexpected output from twig batch

Tags: twig

I have a twig `batch` in my code used to style a list of images. I need to know the position of each image in the batch since they will all be styled differently.

```
{% for mediaItem in mediaItems|batch(9, 'empty') %}
   {{ dump(mediaItem) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This returns the following result:

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => MediaItem {#1135 ▶}
  1 => MediaItem {#1155 ▶}
  2 => MediaItem {#1169 ▶}
  3 => MediaItem {#1180 ▶}
  4 => MediaItem {#1191 ▶}
  5 => MediaItem {#1202 ▶}
  6 => MediaItem {#1213 ▶}
  7 => MediaItem {#1224 ▶}
  8 => MediaItem {#1235 ▶}
]
array:9 [▼
  9 => MediaItem {#1246 ▶}
  10 => MediaItem {#1257 ▶}
  11 => MediaItem {#1268 ▶}
  12 => MediaItem {#1279 ▶}
  13 => MediaItem {#1290 ▶}
  14 => MediaItem {#1301 ▶}
  15 => MediaItem {#1312 ▶}
  16 => MediaItem {#1323 ▶}
  17 => MediaItem {#1334 ▶}
]
array:9 [▼
  0 => MediaItem {#1345 ▶}
  1 => "empty"
  2 => "empty"
  3 => "empty"
  4 => "empty"
  5 => "empty"
  6 => "empty"
  7 => "empty"
  8 => "empty"
]
```

The first and last batch are as I expect but the keys of the second batch don't start from 0.

I've read in the twig documentation that there is an argument `preserve_keys` which I have tried as follows: `{% for mediaItem in mediaItems|batch(9, 'empty', false) %}` but with no result.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or another way to achieve this?

This is on twig 2.4.8.

Comment: This was a know issue and has been fixed in twig 2.7.0 ([demo](https://twigfiddle.com/cklh8p))

Comment: @DarkBee thanks! Updating my Twig version solved the issue.